# NSURLErrorDomain error -1 When trying to download http Live Streaming Video

Tags: ios, swift3, http-live-streaming

I have been trying to download a video from a url using the AVAssetDownloadDelegate. I am able to play the video from the response, but I am unable to download the media using the below code.

I receive this error **" The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1.) "**

This is the code i used

```
@IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!

var configuration : URLSessionConfiguration? = nil

var downloadSession : AVAssetDownloadURLSession? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


      configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "downloadIdentifier")


      downloadSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: configuration!,
                                                    assetDownloadDelegate: self,
                                                    delegateQueue: nil)

    let url = URL(string: "http://sample.vodobox.net/skate_phantom_flex_4k/skate_phantom_flex_4k.m3u8")
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url!)

    let downloadTask = downloadSession?.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset,
                                                              assetTitle: "assetTitle",
                                                              assetArtworkData: nil,
                                                              options: nil)

    // Start task and begin download
    downloadTask?.resume()


    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: (downloadTask?.urlAsset)!)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = view1.bounds
    view1.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()


}
```

This are the delegates I implemented

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("Downloaded to Location : \(location)")
}



func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didLoad timeRange: CMTimeRange, totalTimeRangesLoaded loadedTimeRanges: [NSValue], timeRangeExpectedToLoad: CMTimeRange) {
    var percentComplete = 0.0
    // Iterate through the loaded time ranges
    for value in loadedTimeRanges {
        // Unwrap the CMTimeRange from the NSValue
        let loadedTimeRange = value.timeRangeValue
        // Calculate the percentage of the total expected asset duration
        percentComplete += loadedTimeRange.duration.seconds / timeRangeExpectedToLoad.duration.seconds
    }
    print(percentComplete *= 100)
    // Update UI state: post notification, update KVO state, invoke callback, etc.
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {


    if (error != nil){

        print(error?.localizedDescription)



    }else{

        print("Error")

    }

}
```

Please have a look at this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This HLS download API is broken in many different ways. 
A few thing you can try:

1. Specify the bitrate in makeAssetDownloadTask call (options parameter)
2. Modify their sample app to download your video, this could help you debug see if there is anything wrong with your playlist.
3. implement func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didResolve resolvedMediaSelection: AVMediaSelection) delegate see if it ever gets called.

Comment: Hi @noc, I implemented the function and could see that the delegate was never called. I specified the bit rate too and still I could observe no change. I will try to modify the code from their sample app to see whether it would work and reply soon. Thank you

Comment: oh, I forgot to ask you. Make sure you are not running on simulator. HLS download doesn't work on simulator.

Comment: @noc I am facing same issue for downloading HLS videos. I have tried your solution & for me unc urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didResolve resolvedMediaSelection: AVMediaSelection) function is getting call. So what is exact meaning of it?